# What's going on with the ending of The Martian?

Tags: the-martian, andy-weir

My library copy of *The Martian* by Andy Weir finishes with Mark's rescue by the rest of the Ares 3 crew. The last line is:

> This is the happiest day of my life.

However, the [LibraryThing page for the book](https://www.librarything.com/work/13265773/book/107783907) claims that its last line is:

> It was a nice, boring afternoon.

Googling this sentence gives me, among other things, a questionably-legal version of the book with an additional scene at the end that's not in my physical copy, in which Mark is on Earth.

**Is that scene genuinely part of the book? If so, why is it not in the version I have?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like the final paragraph was [intentionally left out](https://www.librarything.com/topic/163425) of the latest versions of the ebook and audio-books. Andy Weir discusses this in a [recent interview](http://www.allreadable.com/vid/andy-weir-the-martian-talks-at-google-1931849.html) on Allreadable;

> "They're re-recording it from scratch because there were a lot of edits
>   and changes between the original Kindle version and what's releasing
>   now. No significant plot changes, nothing like that, but a lot of the
>   wording. It's much more polished. And it's much better now thanks to
>   Julian at Random House."

I'm guessing that the editing choice was because earlier versions were [self-published](http://www.randomhouse.com/highschool/catalog/display.pperl?isbn=9780804139021&view=qa) whereas the later versions are published by [Random House](http://www.randomhouse.com/book/234102/the-martian-by-andy-weir). The paragraph in question contains a scene where the protagonist swears ***at*** a young child, something which a book publisher might shy away from, especially given that they're intending to licence the book to a Hollywood film.